# What is the correct way to setup multiple logically organized sub folders in a terraform repo?

Tags: directory, structure, terraform, backend, devops

Currently I am working on a infrastructure in azure that comprises of the following:

- resource group
- application gateway
- app service
- etc

everything I have is in one single `main.tf` file which I know was a mistake however I wanted to start from there. I am currently trying to move each section into its own sub folder in my repo. Which would look something like this:

```
terraform-repo/
├── applicationGateway/
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── vars.tf
├── appService/
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── vars.tf
├── main.tf
└── vars.tfvars
```

However when I create this while trying to move over from the single file structure I get issues with my remote state where it wants to delete anything that isn't a part of the currently worked on sub folder. 
For example if I wanted to run `terraform apply applicationGateway` I will get the following:

```
  # azurerm_virtual_network.prd_vn will be destroyed

Plan: 0 to add, 2 to change, 9 to destroy.
```

What is the correct way to setup multiple logically organized sub folders in a terraform repo? Or do I have to destroy my current environment to get it to be setup like this ?

Comment: It is encouraged to have only one module per repository.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are seeing this issue because terraform ignores subfolders, so those resources are not being included at all anymore. You would need to configure the subfolders to be [Terraform Modules](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules), and then include those modules in your root `main.tf`

Comment: Can someone explain motivation behind this? I find it pretty annoying that I need to have all tf files in one directory and not having it organised with subdirectories.

Comment: @trubi only Hashicorp can answer your question!  Anyway, hi MarkB please update the link: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/index.html

Comment: (looks to me like both links work)

Comment: @dur you should take that feedback to HashiCorp. Posting it here isn't going to accomplish anything.

Comment: @dur just because there are some open issues after years doesn't mean there aren't tons of other issues have been fixed and closed out. You seem to be looking more for a place to vent and complain, and this is not the correct venue.

Comment: @MarkB Sorry, I don't want to offend you. I'm not looking or a place to complain. It's just I'm really disappointed about some important issues still not resolved. However, it is open source and I should know it.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you were offensive @dur, no need to apologise. We all get disappointed every now and then. If the world is forced to run without anyone expressing negatives then not only is it not going to run but there's going to be a massive increase in mental health problems... wait...

Answer (score 12):

**update 06/2022 , Complete example :**

Let's say you have the following directories

```
./your-folder
|__ main.tf
|__ variables.tf
|__ output.tf
|__ /modules
    |__ /module-a
        |__ main.tf
        |__ variables.tf
        |__ output.tf
```

Module definition in `./your-folder/modules/module-a/main.tf`:

```
resource "[resource_type]" "my-module-name" {
   ...
}
```

Load module in your root `main.tf` file, so in `./your-folder/main.tf`:

```
module "my-module-instance-name" {
    source = "./modules/module-a"
    other-input-variable = "..."
}
```

Then tell Terraform to load this new module running the following command in your root directory (so `./your-folder`):

```
terraform get
```

Then test your setup with terraform plan.

To use root-level resources in child modules, inject it into child module as input variable.

To use child-level resources in root module, export it from child module with the output instruction.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: important to point out that you can have multiple files in the module directory, regardless of file naming as long as the extension is ".tf" (I took a time to realizes that)

Comment: Is the `modules` directory needed. I'm frustrated with the depth and proliferation of sub-directories in the terraform I'm working with and just wondering how it can be minimised. Can you put `module-a` and all the other module directories directly inside `your-folder` and just not have the `modules` directory?

Comment: What about hyphen vs underscore in directory names? Is there a habit or actual reason to use either one or the other?

Answer (score 3):

One option for maintaining a DRY environment this way is using [Terragrunt](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/)

Terragrunt is a wrapper for Terraform that allows organization and reusable components in a slightly different way than Terraform handles environments.