# Moving terraform configuration files into separate directory removes them from the plan

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have my terraform infrastructure defined in many configuration files as below.

- root
- - data_sources.tf
- - iam.tf
- - glue_connections.tf
- - glue_crawlers.tf
- - glue_catalog.tf
- - glue_jobs.tf
- - provider.tf
- - storage.tf
- - vpc.tf

I wanted to organise them a bit by moving the configuration files starting with "glue_" into their own directory.

- root
- - glue
- - - glue_connections.tf
- - - glue_crawlers.tf
- - - glue_catalog.tf
- - - glue_jobs.tf
- - data_sources.tf
- - iam.tf
- - provider.tf
- - storage.tf
- - vpc.tf

But when I applied the change it removed all of the resources that I moved into the glue directory.

Is there some trick that will allow me to move my configuration files into their own directory without terraform removing/ignoring them?

Note: I am using using terraform cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this happen because Terraform ignore what you have in the subfolders, so the resources in the `glue` directory will not be created.

Indeed, you can create a module `glue` and recall it in the main module.

[Terraform Modules](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules)

EDIT:
I also found an really similar question [What is the correct way to setup multiple logically organized sub folders in a terraform repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60041854/what-is-the-correct-way-to-setup-multiple-logically-organized-sub-folders-in-a-t)