# Deploying terraform using Github action and Monorepo

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I have a single Mono repo with terraform code for all infrastructure. On this repo, I have splited it different sub-folders, each of them as working dir for terraform.

mono-repo
modules
terraform
network
main.tf
variables.tf
datalake
main.tf
variables.tf
cloud-composer
main.tf
variables.tf

Supose that I have made a change in `cloud-compose/main.tf`, is it possible to detect that `cloud-composer` have changed and execute `terraform apply` only for this sub-folder?

Or should I iterate over sub-folders and apply for all of them?

Is it the correct approach? Is there a better one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to setup multiple logically organized sub folders in a terraform repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60041854/what-is-the-correct-way-to-setup-multiple-logically-organized-sub-folders-in-a-t)

Comment: Why not have a centralised main, that includes the modules in it, then just plan / apply that? "is it possible to detect that ... have changed and execute ...  only for this sub-folder?" -- just let terraform manage the change/drift detection itself, that it does anyway when you plan / apply.

Comment: This may answer your question: [How can I run a single Terraform GitHub Actions pipeline that applies multiple terraform resources (each with own state files) at same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76600848/how-can-i-run-a-single-terraform-github-actions-pipeline-that-applies-multiple-t)